# How to Replace [quote]..[/quote] with other HTML

Tags: c#, razor

I have [quote=username]messageText[/quote] saved in database. I want to replace this with :

--div
Posted by 'username' and message is 'messageText'
--div

I want to achieve this in cshtml and username and message is already saved with [quote] tag in db just want the username to appear after 'Posted by' in the above div.

Comment: Hello. Can you shar some code? What have you tried so far? see [ask]

Comment: I have tried to replace [quote] with my html but how do i bring the username because it will be unique for every user

Comment: You can achieve it with a regex, a bit of substring or a parser. The substring method should be the easier. Try to write a bit of code and post it. This how you learn. We are here to help you. Not to write code for you.